# Individual loss of each (final-layer) output of Keras model

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, loss-function, loss

When training a ANN for regression, Keras stores the train/validation loss in a [History object](https://keras.io/callbacks/#history). In the case of **multiple outputs in the final layer** with a [standard loss function](https://keras.io/losses/), i.e. the Mean Squared Error or MSE:

- what does the loss represent in the multi-output scenario? Is it the average/mean of the individual losses of all outputs or is it something else?
- Can I somehow access the loss of each output individually without implementing a custom loss function?

Any hints would be much appreciated.

**EDIT------------**

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(10, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(2))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
```

Re-phrasing my question after adding the snippet:

> How is the loss calculated in the case of two neurons in the output layer and what does the resulting loss represent? Is it the average loss for both outputs?

Comment: Can you give an example model? What do you mean by "multiple outputs in the final layer"?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I added a sample code :)

Comment: For me, I only see one output, which is the output of the dense layer. Do you mean the loss of each sample in a batch?

Comment: there are two outputs since there are two units in the dense layer. My question is how loss is calculated as a **scalar** for a given **vector** of outputs

Answer (score 1):

The standard MSE loss is implemented in Keras as follows:

```
def mse_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)
```

If you now have multiple neurons at the output layer, the computed loss will simply be the mean of the squared-loss of all individual neurons.

If you want the loss of each individual output to be tracked you have to write an own metric for that. If you want to keep it as simple as possible you can just use following metric (it has to be nested since Keras only allows a metric to have inputs y_true and y_pred):

```
def inner_part_custom_metric(y_true, y_pred, i):
    d = y_pred-y_true
    square_d = K.square(d)
    return square_d[:,i] #y has shape [batch_size, output_dim]

def custom_metric_output_i(i):
    def custom_metric_i(y_true, y_pred):
        return inner_part_custom_metric(y_true, y_pred, i)
    return custom_metric_i
```

Now, say you have 2 output neurons. Create 2 instances of this metric:

```
metrics = [custom_metric_output_i(0), custom_metric_output_i(1)]
```

Then compile your model as follows:

```
model = ...
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=SGD(lr=0.01), metrics=metrics)
history = model.fit(...)
```

Now you can access the loss of each individual neuron in the history object. Use following to command to see what's in the history object:

```
print(history.history.keys())
```

Comment: This is a good idea but will not work as each metric must have a distinct name

Answer (score 0):

```
print(history.history.keys())
```

and then:

```
print(history.history['custom_metric_i'])
```

like stated before, will actually print the history for only one dimension!